# Не работает reload(sys)

Tags: python

Добрый день! Имеется код :

```
import sys
reload(sys)
```

В консоли выдает ошибку:

```
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined
```

Comment: `reload` - не `builtin` функция и перед вызовом ее необходимо импортировать `from importlib import reload`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы в python 3, так что:

```
from importlib import reload # для python 3.4+
from imp import reload  # для python 3.0 - 3.3
reload(sys) # для python 2.x
```